# How to use typealias of function type?

Tags: kotlin

how can I use this typalias?

```
typealias MyHandler = (Int, String) -> Unit
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var myHandler = MyHandler(1, "2")
```

Comment: what about something like var myHandler: MyHandler = {a,b -> ....}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a typealias and are getting `interface doesn't have a constructor` error. To my understanding, typealias with function types work with three steps:

1. Define the typealias itself

   ```
   typealias MyHandler = (Int, String) -> Unit
   ```
2. declare an action of that type

   ```
   val myHandler: MyHandler = {intValue, stringValue -> 
    // do something
   }
   ```
3. use that action, e.g.

   ```
   class Foo(val action: MyHandler) {

     val stateOne: Boolean = false

     // ...

     fun bar() {

       if (stateOne) {
         action.invoke(1, "One")
       } else {
         action.invoke(0, "notOne")
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`typealias` are just an alias for the type :) in other words, it's just another name for the type.

Imagine having to write all the time `(Int, String) -> Unit`. With `typealias` you can define something like you did to help out and write less,i.e. instead of:

```
fun Foo(handler: (Int, String) -> Unit)
```

You can write:

```
fun Foo(handler: MyHandler)
```

They also help giving hints, meaning they can give you a way to describe types in a more contextualized way. Imagine implementing an app where in it's entire domain time is represented as an `Int`. One approach we could follow is defining:

```
typealias Time = Int
```

From there on, every time you want to code something specifically with time, instead of using `Int` you can provide more context to others by using `Time`. This is not a new type, it's just another name for an `Int`, so therefore everything that works with integers works with it too.

There's more if you want to have a [look](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [theThapa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838293/14619383) and [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842709/14619383), function typealiases are a way to declare the type of a function. It can be later used.

For example, the following shows a good example of how to declare it and use it:

```
import kotlin.test.*
import java.util.*

//define alias
typealias MyHandler = (Int, Int) -> Int

fun main(args: Array<String>) {


//define the function
val myHandler: MyHandler = {intValue, bValue -> 
intValue + bValue
}

// class Foo takes MyHandler type as parameter to instantiate
class Foo(val action: MyHandler) {

  val stateOne: Boolean = false

  fun bar() {

    if (stateOne) {
      println(action.invoke(1, 45))
    } else {
      println(action.invoke(0, 65))
    }
  }
}

// instantiate Foo class along with constructor whose parameter is of type MyHandler
val f = Foo(myHandler)
f.bar()
}
```